# Result: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, post, parse-platform, sendgrid, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to send an email via a form with SendGrid + Parse Cloud Code Modules. Everything is working fine functionally and the emails are coming through. However, when I look at my logs, I get the following:

```
Result: ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

//main.js

```
var express = require('express');
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid');
sendgrid.initialize("USER", "PASS");

var app = express();

// App configuration section
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body


app.post('/email', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var message = req.body.message;

  sendgrid.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    from: email,
    subject: 'Message from ' + name + ' via Web',
    text: message
  }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) {
      console.log(httpResponse);
      response.success("Email sent!");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      console.error(httpResponse);
      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear to me. You never defined the `response` variable you call. Didn't you mean `res` ? Or `console` ? Don't forget to fix that both in your `success` handler and your `error` handler.

Comment: That's what I figured, but when I do that I get the following:
Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'success'

Comment: Where do you want to log these messages? `console.log` is not what you want? I can't find the doc for the `sendgrid.sendEmail` function :/

Comment: @blex - yeah, unfortunately parse isn't fantastic at providing docs for some of this stuff. Here is where I got this from - https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse

Comment: Ok, then I think they made a mistake. You should post an issue [here](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse/issues), I think it's the best thing you can do to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is not defined, I think you meant to write

```
sendgrid.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    from: email,
    subject: 'Message from ' + name + ' via Web',
    text: message
}, {
    success: function(httpResponse) {
      console.log(httpResponse);
      httpResponse.success("Email sent!");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      console.error(httpResponse);
      httpResponse.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
});
```

BTW: you should always set strict mode via "use strict" - that would catch undefined variables even faster.